# in my rails application the base css is called agents so Webpacker can't find application in /public/packs/manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

how can I configure the webpacker.yml so that instead of looking for application it looks for agents?

in my rails 4 app the main stylesheet is called `agents` not the default `application`:

```
-> % cat app/assets/stylesheets/agents.css.scss
@import '......
```

but webpacker is looking for application, how can I configure it so that it finds the right tag?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Inside `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` you have a stylesheet_pack_tag and there you can set the name of the css file. By default it will be application. Changing it to agents should do the trick.